# LocalNotification - UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName on ios 7.1 Simulator does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator, uilocalnotification

Based on this Tutorial [Simple iOS Alarm Clock Tutorial](http://vimeo.com/29824336) i have implement a AlarmClock App.
The Notification is firing well but without Sound.

To fix this i have tried:
[Fix-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235650/custom-ios-uilocalnotification-sound-does-not-play-possibly-related-to-xcode-up) and unchecked/checked my MacOS Sound-Settings.

What can i do to get a simple AlarmClock-Sound ?
(Info: Youtube-Sound works @ Simulator)

Code:

```
-(void)scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)fireDate
{

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

   UILocalNotification *notification = [UILocalNotification new];
   notification.fireDate = fireDate;
   notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
   notification.alertBody = @"Wake-up... !!!";
   notification.alertAction = @"OK";

   //[notification setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:-1];
   notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1; // increment

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. It is just because the sound of simulator doesn't work so fine. For example, there's no keyboard-click-sound too. If you assign a custom sound to your local notification, it would works.

Answer (score 1):

if your Default Sound Name in you Simulator is not selected then it Might not ring as you are Using `UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName`, I had added a sound FIle in my app bundle and used to play that as a soundName in my code, it used to work every time